# Problem in Solving an Inequality

Tags: inequality

The problem is:

> $Prove$ $that$ $|\sin^2 (x)-\sin^2 (y)|\le |x-y|$ $ for $  $ all $ $ x,y>0$.

*$My$ $work$ :* $$\sin^2 (x)\le|\sin x|\le|x|\le|x-y|+|y|$$ and so is $$|\sin^ 2 (x)-\sin^2 (y)|\le |x-y|+|y|$$ But this is not the actual result I want. I think I have done few mistakes. Isn't it? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

hint: $$(\sin^2(x) - \sin^2(y)) = (\sin(x) - \sin(y))(\sin(x) + \sin(y))$$

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @Shailesh I think they could be alluding to the factorisations $\sin x \pm \sin y = 2\sin\left(\frac{x\pm y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x\mp y}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2x-\sin^2y=\left(\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1-\cos2y}{2}\right)=\frac{\cos2y-\cos2x}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\cos[(x+y)-(x-y)]-\cos[(x+y)+(x-y)]}{2}=\frac{2\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)}{2}$$

where the first equality comes from $\cos2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha,$and the last equality comes from the cosine sum formula

$$=\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)$$

$$\implies \vert \sin^2x-\sin^2y\vert =\vert\sin(x+y)\vert\cdot\vert\sin(x-y)\vert\le1\cdot\vert x-y\vert$$

where the inequality comes from combining $\vert \sin \theta\vert\le1$ for all $\theta$ and $\vert \sin \psi\vert\le\psi$ for all $\psi$, in particular, taking $\theta=x+y,\psi=x-y$.

Comment: $My$ $revised$ $answer$ :
let us define a function f:[a,b] -> R by f(x)=sin^2 (x), x€ [a,b].Then f satisfies all the conditions of Lagrange's mean value theorem.Now by Lagrange's mean value theorem we have :
[f(b)-f(a)]/(b-a)=f'(c), c€ (a,b).but f'(c)= sin 2c <or=1,which clearly indicates that our result holds for all a,b since a and b are are arbitrary real numbers i.e. |sin^2 (a) - sin^2 (b)|<or=|a - b|,for all a,b.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Yep, that works too - I was trying to use a solution that didn't appeal to calculus, but certainly this question responds very well to applications of the mean value theorem.