# Trigonometric inequality of finding a smallest number

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Find the smallest $k$ for which the inequality

$$|\sin^2 (x)-\sin^2 (y)| \leq k|x-y|$$ 
holds for all pairs of $(x,y)$.

I do not know how to proceed to solve this type of problem. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765022/42969.

Comment: Try finding the maximum of $f(x,y) : = \dfrac{\sin^2(x) - \sin^2(y)}{x-y}$?

Comment: Use the MVT to get $$K$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Will that give you the smallest value for $k$?

Comment: I have not computed it now!

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out.